# add view from delegate to all other viewcontrollers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i am doing application in which i want to show the oscillations at the Navigation bar.
I had created a `EAGLEView` from `appdelegate`.

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate,EAGLViewDelegate>
{
    EAGLView* eaglView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)   EAGLView* eaglView;
```

I called all required methods from `AurioTouch` applications delegate to show the waveforms on getting the sound waves.
  it is working well when i tried it for `FirstViewController`.
But when i tried to show it on `SecondViewController`. it is getting crashed.
  so, now i want to add this view ie `eagleView` to every other `viewControllers`.
How to do it?
   I added it as a `subview` to other views like

```
appDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
appDel.eaglView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 320, 100);
appDel.eaglView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[self.view addSubview:appDel.eaglView];
```

In `viewdidload` method.
 any Ideas for this?

Comment: You could add it to the navigation controller.

Comment: ok, tried this [[[_nav1.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] view] addSubview:eaglView]; but still not showing

Comment: try this nav1.visibleViewController

Comment: You will need to call this every time the user changes controller which still isn't ideal i guess

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[nav1.navigationBar addSubview:YouView];
```

If this doesn't work you can subclass a UINavigationController and add this into the initWithRootViewController method:

```
    UINavigationBar *navBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
    [navBar addSubview:YourView];

    [self setValue:navBar forKeyPath:@"navigationBar"];
```

Hope this helps

Sam

Comment: Thanks but I am hiding the navigation bar in view controllers.    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES; any other way to make it working?

Comment: Ah right, in that case you will probably have to use nav1.visibleViewController and add the view on the call of any new view controller. I would highly suggest reading about using mediators in IOS, it makes doing things like this much easier :)

Comment: A mediator is a type of design pattern. The 'Pro Objective-C Design Patterns for IOS' by Apress is very good for these sorts of design patterns in iOS :)